# A fibonacci like Algorithm

Tags: c++

For  f(n) = f(n – 1) + f(n – 2^10),  when 0 <= n < 2^10, f(n)=1 ,

write a function to compute f(n).(not using recursive method)

```
int compute_f(int n)
{
    int result = 0;

    ...

    return result 
}
```

wondering is there any efficient way to do?

Comment: "Doing it in an efficient way" doesn't actually mean "Getting someone else to do it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the same idea of fibonacci and do [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Pseudo code:

```
if n < 0:
    //throw some exception
arr = new int[max(1024,n+1)]
for i = 0 to 1024:
    arr[i] = 1
for i = 1024 to n+1:
    arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-1024]
return arr[n]
```

Converting it to actual code is left for you.

Bonus: You can do it with O(1) extra space by holding an array of size 1024 and manipulating it and remembering your current place (use modolus operator) without changing the time complexity.

Comment: Why the downvote? The only possible criticism could be in the fact that it's expensive in terms of storage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version, similar to the recursive version of Fibonacci.

```
int compute_f(int n)
{
     if( n < 0)
         return -1; //Error
     if(n <= 1024)
         return 1;
     return (compute_f(n-1) + compute_f(n-1024));
}
```